# Extract sub-lists recursively from main list

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list `a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]` and I want to get first 2 elements repeatedly from every 4 elements. So the result will look like this:

```
b1 = [1,2]
b2 = [5,6]
b3 = [9,10]
```

I tried `c = [a[x:x+4] for x in range(0,len(a),4)]` but it only gives `[1,2]`.
How to make it recursive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[a[i] for i in xrange(0, len(a)) if i % 4 < 2 ]
# [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```

If you wish to make an array of arrays, use

```
[[a[i], a[i + 1]] for i in xrange(0, len(a)) if i % 4 == 0]
# [[1, 2], [5, 6], [9, 10]]
```

If wish to assign the result to three variable, use

```
b1, b2, b3 = [[a[i], a[i + 1]] for i in xrange(0, len(a)) if i % 4 == 0]
# b1 = [1, 2], b2 = [5, 6], b3 = [9, 10]
```

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, what if I want to get `[3,4,7,8,11,12]` ?

Comment: Change `< 2` to `>= 2` in the first one, and `i % 4 == 0` with `i % 4 == 2` in the second and third.